# Macbook pro 2017 15' won't connect to WIFI

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, 22.04, macbook

I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 on my 2017 15' Mac but I can't seem to get the WIFI to work. I checked my internet driver and found out that it was BCM43602. After some searching online, I found out that I had to intall the drivers. I did as shown below.

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt update
sudo update-pciids
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo reboot 
sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 txpower 10dBm
```

However, `sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 txpower 10dBm` did not work for me. I am getting

```
Error for wireless request "Set Tx Power" (8B26) :
    SET failed on device wlp3s0 ; Input/output error.
```

When I run the command  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`, I got

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [106b:0173]
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I run the command `dmesg | grep brcm`, I get

```
[    3.078509] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    3.190242] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/2
[    3.191788] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro14,3.txt failed with error -2
[    3.191817] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[    3.540820] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/2
[    3.540863] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
[    3.541674] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43602/2 wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[    3.697394] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    3.771830] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM.hcd'
```

What should I do? I've installed the drivers but for some reason, I cannot connect to the internet.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Also please add output of `dmesg | grep brcm`

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Does the adapter see any wireless networks?

Comment: Yes, it does. It sees the networks but cannot connect to them. It gets stuck at connecting

Comment: This device is problematic on Linux.

Comment: Try `sudo rfkill unblock wifi; sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 txpower 10dBm`

Comment: Also the power can be set by `sudo iw dev wlp3s0 set txpower fixed 10mBm`

Comment: I tried `sudo rfkill unblock wifi; sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 txpower 10dBm`, however I still get `Error for wireless request "Set Tx Power" (8B26) :
    SET failed on device wlp3s0 ; Input/output error.`

Comment: May we also see: `lsmod | grep -e brcm -e wl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It is some time that you asked this question @lordvaderhatessand. Did you find a solution? I have the same problem: I can see Wifi networks but the password is rejected when I connect and I have tried the same steps as you.

Comment: @Jono Please start your own new question.