# Connect to Wi-Fi on MacBook Pro with Ubuntu 22 and Broadcom wireless adapter BCM43602?

Tags: wireless, 22.04, broadcom, macbook-pro

This question is very similar to [Ubuntu 18.04 wireless connections visible but won't connect BCM43602](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091172/ubuntu-18-04-wireless-connections-visible-but-wont-connect-bcm43602) however the solution (the same as below) does not work for me.

The problem: I can see all wireless networks but when I try to connect to one with a valid password, it does not connect and I keep receiving the authentication required prompt.

The steps I have tried to solve the problem (note, I had no errors for these commands):

```
sudo apt purge bcwl-kernel-source
sudo apt update
update-pciids
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer linux-firmware
sudo reboot
```

(These steps come from [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers))

Then once rebooted, I ran `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 txpower 20dBm`.

The result: the problem still persists.

Can someone provide some assitance?

I include below the output from some commands which may be useful:

`lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [106b:0157]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 80
    Region 0: Memory at 82400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 2: Memory at 82000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
```

`rfkill list all`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*`

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb.
```

`sudo dmesg | grep b43` empty

FYI, this is a [MacBook Pro 2016 13 inch](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP748?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

PS, I also found [Macbook pro 2017 15' won't connect to WIFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413500/macbook-pro-2017-15-wont-connect-to-wifi) which is similar but there is no answer.

Comment: I was having similar problems with a BCM4331, so ymmv... I got the driver downloaded, built and installed using `sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source`. I gave up trying to use `iwconfig` to connect when I read that it didn't support WPA/WPA2 authentication, only WEP. After `sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant` and editing `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` to contain my Wifi's SSID and password it was able to connect with `sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp3s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext` and get an IP address, netmask, gateway with `sudo dhclient wlp3s0`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is not the answer yet I'm sorry.
I would post it inside a comment but it is too limited for this case.
I have a MacBook Pro Mid 2012 with Ubuntu 22.04.1.
The Wifi is working but sometimes it fails. If I restart the system Wifi works again.

Here is the output inside the terminal for one command that @Jono also posted above:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network
```

chicortiz@chicortiz:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)

```
Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:00f5]

Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-

Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-

Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes

Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17

Region 0: Memory at a0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

Capabilities: <access denied>

Kernel driver in use: wl

Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

chicortiz@chicortiz:~$

##############

Greetings!

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I dont see an answer?! Restarting changes nothing for me.

Comment: Hi Jono, unfortunately this is not the answer yet, I'm sorry. 
I was posting some data in a hope to add a clue for anyone looking at this post.
If you think that it would be interesting if I post more information about my system please just send me the commands and I will add the terminal prints here. Please fell free to delete my post if you want.