# MacBookPro 2017 won't connect to wifi (22.04)

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, broadcom, macbook-pro

I'm trying to connect my 2017 15" MacBookPro to my home Wifi. Initial situation after setup was, that my neighbours wifi would show up in gnome-control-center (aka Settings), but mine wouldn't.

According to lspci, this laptop has a

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 02)
```

Unfortunately, this exact pciid is not listed in [the canonical answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395/1199587). So I tried what is recommended for most devices:

```
# apt update
# apt upgrade
# update-pciids
# apt install firmware-b43-installer linux-firmware
# reboot
# iwconfig wlp3s0 txpower 10dBm
```

After that, my home network appeared in the gnome-control-center, but when I tried connecting, it keeps asking for my wifi key. (Which I've checked and rechecked...)

I can connect to the same wifi, if I boot the macbook into macos.

This is a freshly installed device, so no other drivers were ever installed, apart from what is shipped by baseline ubuntu. What should I try next?

PS: I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454253/connect-to-wi-fi-on-macbook-pro-with-ubuntu-22-and-broadcom-wireless-adapter-bcm) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413500/macbook-pro-2017-15-wont-connect-to-wifi) question, unfortunately, neither has an answer.

```
# dmesg | grep brcm
[   14.335238] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   14.354625] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM.hcd'
[   14.442383] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/2
[   14.442422] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro14,3.bin failed with error -2
[   14.444299] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Apple Inc.-MacBookPro14,3.txt failed with error -2
[   14.444676] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[   14.777565] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie for chip BCM43602/2
[   14.777613] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
[   14.778545] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43602/2 wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c
[   14.815923] brcmfmac 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[  413.686158] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[  516.062505] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[  798.160480] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[  824.923318] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
[  831.842586] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table err:-52
```

[output of wireless-info](https://pastebin.com/qK0PgVL4)

Comment: Can you force your wifi router to use a fixed channel between 1-11

Comment: I believe the correct driver is not b43/bcma, et al, but brcmfmac. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep brcm`

Comment: @Jeremy31 huh, that helped. I don't understand why, but it did.

Comment: @chili555 question edited.

Comment: @chili555 If you still think I should be using a different driver, I'm still interested. Messing with txpower seems wrong.

Comment: Just showing us a list of the commands isn't helpful. We need to see the results of the failing commands.  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Are b43, bcma, etc. still loaded? `lsmod | grep -e b43 -e bcma`

Comment: @chili555 That command produces no output. However brcmfmac is among the loaded modules (see output of wireless-info script)

Comment: @waltinator added output of wireless-info

Comment: "*Quality=18/70*" If you take your laptop right next to the router and run: `sudo iwlist scan` does the link quality improve? To what numbers?

Comment: The best I got was `Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm` when standing right next to the AP.

Answer (score 0):

Your readings strongly suggest that one or both of the antenna wires are not firmly snapped in place on your wireless card.

[image]

At a distance of two meters or less, I'd expect a signal strength of *Quality=70/70*. I recommend that a qualified technician examine and repair your computer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Although it will take some time until I can do that.